# How to integrate coinbase commerce Webhook API in Django

Tags: python, django, api, webhooks, coinbase-api

I am trying to integrate Coinbase Commerce Webhook API in my Django App; but it seems am doing things in the right way. I have searched the web for more than 2 days but no solution available for this. Coinbase commerce official documentation did not provide way to integrate this in Django. Please your help will be appreciated. This is what I have tried; but keep on throwing an error.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from coinbase_commerce.error import WebhookInvalidPayload, SignatureVerificationError
from coinbase_commerce.webhook import Webhook
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

WEBHOOK_SECRET = settings.COINBASE_SECRET

@csrf_exempt
def payment_webhook(request):
  
    request_data = request.data.decode('utf-8')
    request_sig  = request.headers.get('X-CC-Webhook-Signature', None)

    try:
        event = Webhook.construct_event(request_data, request_sig, WEBHOOK_SECRET)
    except (WebhookInvalidPayload, SignatureVerificationError) as e:
        return HttpResponse(e, status=400)

    print("Received event: id={id}, type={type}".format(id=event.id, type=event.type))
    return HttpResponse('ok', status=200)
```

Comment: "but keep on throwing an error": what was the error?

Comment: Bad Request: / "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 53

Comment: Is there any extra information in the error response?

Comment: Have you found the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, but since I'm only creating an endpoint to receive the webhook from 'charge:confirmed' which confirms that someone payed. I decided to do the validation of a request differently.

Upon receiving a request from the webhook, I check in the `event['data']['timeline']` object if the `status` `COMPLETED` is present which according to: https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/ specifies that the payment has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you have to use `request.body.decode('utf-8')` instead of `request.data.decode('utf-8')`

```
    request_data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
```